# Using substring-after to search text in XPath query

Tags: xml, search, xpath, substring

I trying to parse a string in an XML node by using an XPath query which requires that I strip out a substring and read the remaining value.  The substring may have a dynamic amount of whitespace before and after it before I can get to the value, so it would be helpful to have some sort of a indexOf function to use in the XPath.  I'm trying to use substring-after, but there is a good chance the XPath is 1.0, which according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333249/how-to-apply-the-xpath-function-substring-after) might make this more difficult to accomplish.  The following is an example of the XML I am trying to parse:

```
<root>
   <myField>     StringToParse        7</myField>
</root>
```

I'm trying to get at the value 7 in the string, which would seem possible with some combination of substring-after and normalize-space.  I'm not entirely sure I'm using it correctly because no matter which way I try to use it, the result is either a null value or the entire string, with the substring not removed.

The way I am able to return the entire value (the lesser of two evils) is:

```
/myField[substring-after(.,'StringToParse')]
```

which I would hope would return '        7'  Could anyone let me know I'm doing wrong with the syntax, or if there is an alternate method I should be using to accomplish what I want?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation of the problems you are having and for two solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The way I am able to return the entire
>   value (the lesser of two evils) is:
>   `/myField[substring-after(.,'StringToParse')]`,
>   which I would hope would return ' 7'
>   Could anyone let me know I'm doing
>   wrong

You are close, but there are at least two problems with the expression:

`/myField[substring-after(.,'StringToParse')]`

1. **`myField` is not the top element in the document and this expression requests that the top element be selected** and that this element's name is `myField`. If evaluated against the provided XML document, no node would be selected, because the top element in the provided XML document is named `root`.
2. **The function call to `substring-after()` is inside a *predicate*.** This means that the top node named `myField` is to be selected depending on the value of the call to `substring-after()`, converted to boolean. This is clearly what you want -- you dont want a node -- you want a string!

**Solution**:

```
substring-after(/*/myField, 'StringToParse')
```

**evaluates to** (without the quotes):

```
"        7"
```

**A better solution may be**:

```
normalize-space(substring-after(/*/myField, 'StringToParse'))
```

**this evaluates to just**:

```
"7"
```

Comment: this is how I imagined it would work, however this isn't working when I try it in any sort of online XPath tester.  It just bombs out.  In my live scenario, the query results in an empty string (probably a null value) This could be a result of how the XPath is processed in .net, which is the platform I am using to evaluate the query.  I will do a little more testing and get back to you.

Comment: @Mike: Then you haven'r shown us the real XML document. I suspect that it may have a default namespace and this is the most FAQ with a wellknown answer.

Comment: The real XML document is basically the same thing, but this XPath isn't being evaluated in XSL, it's actually being evaluated by the System.Xml.XmlNode.SelectSingleNode(string xPath) method in .net.  I suspect this is where the problem is because that method returns an XmlNode and not a string.  When I've tried this using the Xpath Query tool here http://www.xmlme.com/XpathTool.aspx the error it gives me when trying to evaluate this expression is "Expression must evaluate to a node-set"

Comment: @Mike: Use XPathNavigator.Evaluate()