# How to apply substring-after and substring-before functions

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

My html structure as below

```
<td class="opps">1:2</td>
```

I am trying split value of td with XPath as below

```
.//*[contains(@class, 'opps')]/text()[normalize-space(substring-after(., ':'))]
.//*[contains(@class, 'opps')]/text()[normalize-space(substring-before(., ':'))]
```

But value returns **1:2**

How can i extract **1** and **2** separately?

I am also using HtmlNodeNavigator and HtmlAgilityPack.

What is the wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Silly question, but if you can get the `1:2` value, why not split it in C# after parsing it out?

Comment: look at this answer on `SO` someone asked a similar question with a provided solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964642/using-substring-after-to-search-text-in-xpath-query

Comment: @Oded Beacuse i would like to extract value with XPath.

Comment: Not really answering my question. "Because I want to". Do you have any specific technical issue that means you must do it in XPath?

Comment: it applies using XPATH unless I am reading what he is wanting incorrectly..

Comment: @DJKRAZE Thank you. i tried that question's suggestions but i doesn't work.

Comment: @Oded OK i changed my answer. Because my application's workflow need to use XPath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found a solution after more search.

if use **HtmlNodeNavigator** or **XPathNavigator**, solution is possible as below

```
string _result1 = <HtmlNodeNavigator>.Evaluate("substring-after(.//*[contains(@class, 'opps')]/text(), ':')") as string; 
string _result2 = <XPathNavigator>.Evaluate("substring-before(.//*[contains(@class, 'opps')]/text(), ':')") as string;
```

Comment: Kudos for finding your own answer. I've deleted mine.

Comment: Well, I've been dead wrong in saying that it was impossible (because I was only thinking in terms of the Agility Pack and `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument`), so it's only fair.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, you can use c# method for this too.
For example;

```
string strVal = "1:2";
string[] splitedStrArr = strVal.Split(':'); 
// you have now 2 elements inside the array. You can use it separately
```