# PHP XPath substring-after only returning first result

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am doing some HTML scraping and have hit a wall with this one query. I am trying to return a set of values from the following HTML page structure:

```
<div id="product-grid">
    <ul>
        <li><div class="price">Cash Price: $20.00</div></li>
        <li><div class="price">Cash Price: $30.00</div></li>
        <li><div class="price">Cash Price: $40.00</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the `"$20.00"` prices returned in a list. If I use the following XPath:

```
id('product-grid')//p[@class="price"]
```

I get a result list of all the "Cash Price: $40.00". If I try the following query:

```
substring-after(id('product-grid')//p[@class="price"] , "Price: ")
```

I get the correct output, but only get the first result. Anyone know how I can get all results?

I am running `PHP5.3.3` with `libxml 2.7.8` for the `XPath`. I am calling the xpath as follows:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $html ); 
$resultset= $xpath->query($query);
```

I have been googling like mad trying to find out why this is happening! Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but I don't think that this is possible in one step. As far as I know XPath 1.0 does not support function calls at the end of an XPath path. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333249/how-to-apply-the-xpath-function-substring-after/334251#334251) indicates the same.

<del>Furthermore you must not use `id('product-grid')` as the first path part because the id is on the root element and does not need to be selected specially. If your sample XML is just a fragment of a larger XML document, the `id()` might be necessary though.</del>

The following works as expected:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML('<div id="product-grid">
 <ul>
  <li><div class="price">Cash Price: $20.00</div></li>
  <li><div class="price">Cash Price: $30.00</div></li>
  <li><div class="price">Cash Price: $40.00</div></li>
</ul>
</div>');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
foreach ($xpath->query('//div[@class="price"]') as $n) {
    var_dump(substr($n->nodeValue, strpos($n->nodeValue, '$')));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use substring after getting your list.

```
 id('product-grid')//div[@class="price"][substring-after(., 'Price: ')]
```

This should work.

**EDIT :** This seems to be working. However I can't test the return value as I don't know how to get the substring'd value. What do you use ?

Comment: Using a function on the axis is an XPath 2.0 feature.  Probably not available in standard PHP environment. You should be able to apply it to a predicate filter:  `id('product-grid')//p[@class="price"][substring-after(., 'Price: ')].  Also, the sample XML shows `div` elements with `@class`, but the example XPath (and your answer) expect `p` to have `@class`.

Comment: @Mads Hansen, post edited to comply with 1.0. I used OP's code so I used p. Changed it to div indeed.

Answer (score 1):

**The wanted processing cannot be specified just as a single XPath 1.0 expression**, because by definition any function that expects a single string argument but is given a node-set, takes the string value of the first only (in document order) node of this node-set.

Also, unlike XPath 2.0 in XPath 1.0 it isn't allowed to specify a function call as a location step.

**Therefore, one solution is to issue this XPath expression**:

```
substring-after((id('product-grid')//p[@class="price"])[$k], "Price: ")
```

`N` times, substituting `$k` in each expression with `1,2,..., N`, where `N` is the result of evaluating another XPath expression:

```
count(id('product-grid')//p[@class="price"])
```

**Using XPath 2.0 one can do this with this simple and single expression**:

```
id('product-grid')//p[@class="price"]/substring-after(., "Price: ")
```

which when evaluated produces exactly the wanted sequence of strings.