# XPath substring-after

Tags: c#, xpath

Given the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<purchaseOrder orderDate="1999-10-20">
    <shipTo country="US">
        <name>Alice Smith</name>
        <street>123 Maple Street</street>
        <city>Mill Valley</city>
        <state>CA</state>
        <zip>90952</zip>
    </shipTo>
    <billTo country="US">
        <name>Robert Smith</name>
        <street>8 Oak Avenue</street>
        <city>Old Town</city>
        <state>PA</state>
        <zip>95819</zip>
    </billTo>
    <comment>Hurry, my lawn is going wild!</comment>
    <items>
        <item partNum="872-AA">
            <productName>Lawnmower</productName>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
            <USPrice>148.95</USPrice>
            <comment>Confirm this is electric</comment>
        </item>
        <item partNum="926-AA">
            <productName>Baby Monitor</productName>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
            <USPrice>39.98</USPrice>
            <shipDate>1999-05-21</shipDate>
        </item>
    </items>
</purchaseOrder>
```

how do I select the '98' from the USPrice in the 2nd item. 
I've tried:

```
purchaseOrder/items/item[USPrice[text()='39.98']]/USPrice/substring-after(.,'.')
```

but it keep giving me the error `'has an invalid token'`

if I try:

```
purchaseOrder/items/item[USPrice[text()='39.98']]/USPrice/text()[substring-after(.,'.')]
```

or

```
purchaseOrder/items/item[USPrice[text()='39.98']]/USPrice[substring-after(text(),'.')]
```

I get `'39.98'` which is wrong too.

I'm testing using the site here:

http://www.xmlme.com/XpathTool.aspx

Answer (score 2):

strictly speaking you cannot do this using xpath 1.0

using XSLT the following would work, but i don't think this is what you require

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(purchaseOrder/items/item[2]/USPrice,'.')"/>
```

please refer to this similar question for more information

[How to apply the XPath function 'substring-after'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333249/how-to-apply-the-xpath-function-substring-after)

Comment: Do you know of a XPath 2.0 for .NET?

Comment: @smolesen Check the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1525299/26396

Comment: I know that .NET only supports XSLT v1.0 and so I suspect its XPATH v1.0 also. I think there are 3rd party implementations, this link has more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525299/xpath-and-xslt-2-0-for-net

Comment: I've wrapped it into some Xslt and did it that way around... thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

**The XPath expression you are after is**:

```
substring-after(/purchaseOrder/items/item[2]/USPrice, '.')
```

**You can evaluate this XPath expression directly in C# code** (without XSLT) using `XPathNavigator.Evaluate()`

Answer (score 0):

Save the value of `/purchaseOrder/items/item[2]/USPrice` into a variable (say Price), and then use `$Price - floor($Price)` to calculate the factional portion of the price.

Using `substring-after()` will fail to return anything if the value is an even number of dollars, which could cause the remainder of the transform to return incorrect results.