# (Xpath) How do I get a specific numeric value?

Tags: html, xpath, google-chrome-devtools, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

How do I get a specific numeric value?

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWaIN.png)

how can I get only the digit "6" ?

example "ตอนที่ 6" i need only output for "6" or " 6 "

i'm try `//li[@class='active']/text()` for simple get text, but i not sure how should i do next

Comment: Have a look at substring-after. I.e. see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/334251/3710053

Comment: i'm try //li[@class='active']/text()[substring-after(. , 'ตอนที่')]   still output "ตอนที่ 6"  :(

Comment: everything inside square brackets is called the predicate. They are meant as filter , not to give results. See the answer of @zx485, how to solve your question

Comment: By posting the XML as an image, you've ensured that no-one can test their proposed answer to be sure that it works. This may be why you're getting answers that don't work for you.

Comment: See how to get only the digits in any given string - below :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(//li[@class='active']/text(),'ตอนที่ '),'&quot;'))
```

You can also use XPath-2.0's `fn:replace` function to use a RegEx to filter the string:

```
normalize-space(replace(//li[@class='active']/text(),'.*&#x0A;\s*&quot;.*(\d+)\s*&quot;.*','$1'))
```

This RegEx may have to be adjusted. It consists of several parts:

1. `.*&#x0A;` matches the whole "::before" line
2. `\s*&quot;.*` matches the string `" ตอนที่`
3. `(\d+)` selects one or more numbers later copied to the output with `$1`
4. `\s*&quot;.*` matches the rest of the line  `" = 50`

Comment: Text is not selected Or is there something I missed?  https://prnt.sc/83vzhFIVGn3J

Comment: I added the `/text()` to the end. I tested it, but there are sometimes tiny differences between the parsers. Maybe this does work better.

Comment: If this doesn't work either, you can try adding a `[1]` near the end the XPath-expression: `//li[@class='active'][1]/text()`.

Comment: it still doesn't work https://prnt.sc/3myMQCgHLac3

Comment: Can you provide the XML? Maybe the value is created dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this, ***without even knowing what non-digit characters could be there***, is using the **double-translate method**:

```
    translate(//li[@class='active']/text(),
              translate(//li[@class='active']/text(), '0123456789', ''),
              '')
```

**Explanation**:

1. The inner `translate(//li[@class='active']/text(), '0123456789', '')` gets all non-digit characters in the first argument.
2. The outer `translate()` replaces all those non-digit characters, found in the inner `translate()` with the empty string.
3. What remains are only the digit characters

---

**XSLT - based verification**:

*Given this simplified XML document*:

```
<t>ตอนที่ 6</t>
```

*The following transformation evaluates the correct (solution) XPath expression and outputs the result of this evaluation*:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., translate(., '0123456789', ''), '')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The wanted result is produced**:

```
6
```